# How to handle different screen size

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

In my application I am using one JFrame and multiple jpanels.
I make the JFrame fullScreen with `setExtendedState()` method. In the main jFrame I load jpanels during runtime. When I load jPanel I use jPanel.setBound(0, 0, 1000, 500).

This looks fine in `1024 x 756` size screens. But when screen size changes The jPanels look very small. 
Is it possible to maintain the ratio of the jPanels including the other components.

I do not like to use JInternalFrame to handle MDI. Because this looks very ugly when the JInternalFrame is maximized.

I am using null layout in the panels.

Comment: Always prefer `percentages` than `px`

Comment: **I am using null layout in the panels** - Why?

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space.  Another things they handle with great ability, is ***different screen sizes.***

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use **"GridBagLayout".**